# can you change the field name using Enhanced Page Layout editor?

Tags: force.com

I have my 401 tommorow, and supposedly you can change the field name with the Enhanced Page Layout editor, but i don't see how. Is this possible?

Comment: Where did you get that info from? You can't change the field names, but you can edit section headers.

Comment: it was an online test, and that was the "right answer"

Comment: @nivyaj A lot of those online tests are next to useless. I've seen far too many of them where they're just plain wrong.

Comment: Completely agree with @LaceySnr. When preparing for my admin exam, I tried one of the ones on proprofs and after three questions, closed the page. The answers were no where near correct.

Comment: Dont trust the answers out there... maybe you could read those questions, answers are wrong most of the time

Comment: ok... thanks for the advice...  FYI- that question didn't come up on the test this morning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to modify field names or labels in the page layout editor. The only text you can modify in the page layout editor are the section headers.